# Host Gator site not loading css file

Tags: html, css, http-status-code-404

I just recently registered a doamin name with host gator. I uploaded my index.html file and the style.css file into the public_domain directory on host gator using FTP (Filezilla). When I go to the URL [Dylan's Portfolio](http://www.dylandavenport.com) I can see the site content in the index.html file but none of the css rules apply. I inspected the page with the console and I get a 404 error saying the css file cannot be found. I have linked the css file in my index.html file using both relative and absolute paths and I still cannot figure it out. Help please :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Directory Structure Issue.

Place the `style.css` in a `css` folder within the root_directory

```
root_directory
 |-css
   |-style.css
```

or

edit your html

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
```

Comment: Yes! All i did was put the style.css file in a css folder and then put that into the public_html folder where as before I just had the style.css file in the public_html folder by itself. Thanks a bunch.

Answer (score 1):

This is werid, i think it is because of the version i paid on hostgator, but i also had this problem:

[www.mysite.com](http://www.mysite.com) didnt let me open any .js .minjs .css .png .jpg etc, no matter the folder and no matter another issue related with the protocol (http or https)

i had to solve it with .htaccess file on each folder css, img, js etc like this.

```
RewriteEngine on    
RewriteCond &#37;{REQUEST_URI} ^\\.(gif|jpe?g|png)$ [NC]    
RewriteRule .? - [F,L]
```

maybe its not the best but works